# How to @Inject a HttpSession object in a service layer (DAO) class in GWT using Guice?

Tags: gwt, dependency-injection, guice, httpsession, requestfactory

I have such a dirty code in my GWT app, some of the classes of my service layer depend on an [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) object. So for example, in one of my DAO (which was a GWT-RPC endpoint) I have something like this :

```
public class MyExampleDAO extends RemoteServiceServlet {
   public findItems() {
       // here I need to get the object session to retrieve the currently logged in user in order to query for all its items...
   }
}
```

The problem is that, I am currently migrating the code to use RequestFactory. My DAO will not be a GWT-RPC endpoint anymore. So no need to extend RemoteServiceServlet then ...

Do you know how I can get/inject (probably with [Guice](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/)) my dependency to HttpSession Object, knowing that my class does not extend RemoteServiceServlet anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getThreadLocalRequest().getSession()` should do it. `RequestFactoryServlet` has a similar (but static) `getThreadLocalRequest()` method that you can access from your service.
Otherwise, you can get Guice to inject a `Provider<HttpSession>`, have a look at these projects https://github.com/mgenov/injecting-request-factory and https://github.com/etiennep/injected-requestfactory for some sample code using Guice with RequestFactory.

Comment: thanks a lot Thomas,

I will try it I'll let you know when it's ok

again, thanks a lot for your help