# How to inject request-scoped HttpSessions in sitebricks methods on GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, guice, httpsession, sitebricks

I have the following [sitebricks](https://github.com/dhanji/sitebricks) servlet. `Foo.get()` is accessible as a `GET` at `/foo/bar`. I deployed the servlet to [GAE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/).

```
@Service
@At("/foo")
@Singleton
public class Foo {
  @Get
  @At("/bar")
  public Reply<?> bar(Request<String> request, HttpSession session) {
    // access request scoped HttpSession 
  }
}
```

If I understand sitebricks correctly, both Request and HttpSession are injected by sitebricks (potentially with the help of [Guice](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/)). It will also ensure that the HttpSession is local to the current request. Concurrent requests will be executed on the same instance of `Foo` since the class is annotated with `@Singleton` (see [Guice docs](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Scopes)). But even with concurrent requests arriving on the same JVM, each invocation of `bar()` will have it's own HttpSession based on the JSESSIONID passed in by the client. **Are all those assumptions valid?**

When running load tests against my app, I have noticed that at a very low rate the HttpSession passed in by sitebricks/Guice is null. I am troubleshooting this with Google's support at the moment. But apart from GAE - What could cause this from the perspective of sitebricks/Guice?

I [found a code snippet](https://code.google.com/p/google-sitebricks/source/browse/trunk/sitebricks/src/main/java/com/google/sitebricks/binding/GaeFlashCache.java?r=117) that injects a Provider into the constructor. Does that mean I can/should get the HttpSession by calling `Provider.get()` instead of letting sitebricks inject it as a method parameter?

**Related Questions:**

- [Provider<HttpSession> not getting injected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873877/providerhttpsession-not-getting-injected)
- [How to @Inject a HttpSession object in a service layer (DAO) class in GWT using Guice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225542/how-to-iinject-an-httpsession-object-in-a-service-layer-dao-class-in-gwt-usin)
- [Inject @SessionScoped value into filter with Guice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333790/guice-inject-session-scoped-value-into-filter)

**Updates**

- I removed the HttpSession parameter from all the servlet methods like `bar`. I injected a `Provider<HttpSession>` into the servlet and call `provider.get()` to get the session. The tests that I ran so far indicate that this is more reliable than getting `HttpSession` out of the parameters. That said, I am not sure if the session is provided by sitebricks or GAE itself. **Is the HttpSession provided by the servlet container?**

Answer (score 0):

Normally I inject HttpServletRequest into the service class first, and then get HttpSession object from the request, which has been working well for me.

For example:

```
@At("/preview")
@Service
public class PreviewService {

  @Inject
  private HttpServletRequest request;

  // It's similar if we need to modify response directly
  @Inject
  private HttpServletResponse response;

  @Get
  public Reply<?> get() {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    ... ...
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.